# How do you reuse a before_script from a shared yml file in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I know that you can reuse blocks of code in a before script using yaml anchors:

```
.something_before: &something_before
- echo 'something before'   


before_script:
  - *something_before
  - echo "Another script step"
```

but this doesn't seem to work when the .something_before is declared in a shared `.yml` file via the `include:file`. It also does not seem that `extends` works for `before_script`. Does anyone know a way of reusing some steps in a `before_script` from a shared `.yml` file?

EDIT: My use case is that I have 2 gitlab projects with almost identical before_script steps. I don't want to have to change both projects whenever there's a change, so I have a third, separate Gitlab project that has a .yml template that I am including via include:file in both projects. I want to put all the common code in that shared template, and just have like two lines before_script for the git project that has the two extra steps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yaml anchors don't work with included files. You need to use the `extends` keyword. But what you want to achieve won't work with `before_script` as code in your template will be overwritten in the job which uses the template if there is a `before_script` as well.

Do you really need a before_script in your specific job or can you achieve the same with a normal `script`? If yes you can do something like this:

Template File:

```
.something_before:
  before_script:
    - echo 'something before'
    - echo 'something more before'
```

Project Pipeline:

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: '/something_before.yml'

stages:
  - something

something:
  stage: something
  extends: .something_before
  script:
    - echo 'additional stuff to do'
```

And your `before_script` section will be merged into the something job and executed before the `script` part.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`!reference` tag.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags)

```yaml
.something:
  before_script:
    - echo 'something before'   


before_script:
  - !reference [".something", "before_script"]
  - echo "Another script step"
```

Comment: Nice! By adding this to the end of your `before_script`s, you can call "inherted" `before_script`s and avoid them being overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

See if [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#include-multiple-cicd-configuration-files-as-a-list) (November 2020) does make it easier:

> ### Include multiple CI/CD configuration files as a list
>
> Previously, when adding multiple files to your CI/CD configuration using the `include:file` syntax, you had to specify the project and ref for each file. In this release, you now have the ability to specify the project, ref, and provide a list of files all at once. This prevents you from having to repeat yourself and makes your pipeline configuration less verbose.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_6/list.png -- Include multiple CI/CD configuration files as a list]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includefile)) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26793).

---

And even, with [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#include-the-same-cicd-template-multiple-times) (March 2022):

> ### Include the same CI/CD template multiple times
>
> Previously, trying to have standard CI/CD templates that you reuse in many places was complicated because each template could only be included in a pipeline once.
>
> We dropped this limitation in this release, so you can include the same configuration file as many times as you like.
> This makes your CI/CD configuration more flexible as you can define identical includes in multiple nested configurations, and rest assured that there will be no conflicts or duplication.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-nested-includes-with-duplicate-includes-entries) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28987).

Answer (score 0):

You can use extends without any problem, but you will need to overwrite the entire `before_script` block.

If you want to change just a piece of your before_script, use a shell script to do it

Set the if condition inside of your template

```
before_script
  - | 
    if [ condition ]
    then
      commands here
    fi
```

AFTER EDIT: You can use variables to achieve it

Project 1: `VAR = command 1`

Project 2: `VAR = command 2`

You can set the content of env var on the gitlab-ci.yml file or on the CI/CD settings in each project!

Comment: I have edited my post to include more relevant information. In my case would I just put your code inside of the shared template, with the "condition" being the name of the project that has the extra steps?

Comment: yes! and now I put an another approach... with variables